# What am I missing to complete the Coursier scala development environment setup?

Tags: java, scala, jvm, coursier

I am trying to set up a scala development environment on my Mac (MacOS Big Sur 11.5.2).
I have installed Coursier using homebrew following the official [coursier documentation](https://get-coursier.io/docs/cli-installation#macos-brew-based-installation).

However when I run
`cs setup --jvm adopt:11`, I get the following error

```
Checking if a JVM is installed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Error while getting https://github.com/shyiko/jabba/raw/master/index.json: download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://github.com/shyiko/jabba/raw/master/index.json
    at coursier.jvm.JvmIndex$.$anonfun$load$5(JvmIndex.scala:141)
    at coursier.jvm.JvmIndex$.$anonfun$load$5$adapted(JvmIndex.scala:139)
    at coursier.util.Task$.$anonfun$flatMap$extension$1(Task.scala:14)
    at coursier.util.Task$.$anonfun$flatMap$extension$1$adapted(Task.scala:14)
    at coursier.util.Task$.wrap(Task.scala:84)
    at coursier.util.Task$.$anonfun$flatMap$2(Task.scala:14)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:307)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
```

Previously I have tried to install JVM manually but then setup fails when trying to install coursier itself.
I have found an issue to similar [problem](https://github.com/coursier/coursier/issues/1989) however the suggestion did not work for me.

Comment: I may suggest asking in the `#tooling` channel of the [**Scala Discord**](https://discord.gg/9jBeMbFu)